# How to get node to pickup on layout.ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm using Node.JS, Express, and ejs. I'm trying to create a layout to be used by all of my views. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10833187/69742), however it doesn't appear to be being picked up. I have a `views` directory with my views. In it, I have my layout.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
    <%- body %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and then I have my index.ejs view:

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
<p>Testnet status: <%= testnet %></p>
```

And then I render it like so:

```
res.render('index', { title: r.name, testnet: r.testnet });
```

After doing this though, the layout isn't picked up. No `<html>` tag is rendered to the screen. I even tried adding this to my app.js

```
app.set('view options', { layout: true });
```

but that didn't work either. How can I get my layout to be rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that answer refers to Express 2 that used to support layouts out of the box, if you are using express 3, note that layouts are no more included in default, you have to install one of the layout engines out there.

used to partial and blocks from django world, I've decided to use [ejs-locals](https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals), using it your .ejs files will have to start with a line like:

```
<% layout('layout') -%>
```